# AWS ElasticSearch Migration to another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to migrate my AWS ES domain from Singapore region to Mumbai region. My backup bucket is inside Singapore region,but when I put my Mumbai region domain inside the python script I am getting the below error.

`{"message":"Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'ap-southeast-1'. "}`

I have changed IAM access key & also give permission to pass the role for the Mumbai ElasticSearch domain to that user.

Am I missing something here or following wrong steps?

Comment: I have done some research and found the below solution

Comment: 1) take a snapshot of Singapore region's Elasticsearch in the Singapore region's bucket
2) replicate this bucket's data into the target region's bucket which is Mumbai.
3) restore the data from the targeted Mumbai region's bucket to the Mumbai region Elasticsearch

Again here, lots of time is consuming for this process as my data is around 600GB.. what could be solution for this to migrate data speedily.